Find all A such that $\text{det}(A+B\bar{B})\geq0$

Find all A such that $$ \text{det} (A+B\overline{B})\in\mathbb{R}\text{ and }\geq0$$ for all $B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$

I was inspired by this post and therefore there are clear $A$'s satisfying the statement: $A=kI_n$, where $k\geq0.$ What I want to ask is that whether these are the only solutions or not. For $n=1$, the answer is obvious: $A  \geq 0$.
A intuitive approach for $n=2$ is let $B=kI_n$ and $k\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
to get $\text{det} (A+B\overline{B})=\text{det} (A+k\overline{k}I_n)\geq0$ and $\text{det} (A+B\overline{B})=\text{det} (A+k\overline{k}(-I_n))\geq0$. Therefore, if we assume the eigen values of A are $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ we have $(\lambda_1+\lambda)(\lambda_2+\lambda)\geq0,\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{R}.$ This implies $\lambda_1=\overline{\lambda_2}.$ Simlarly for $n\geq3,$ we can get $\prod_{i=1}^n(\lambda_i+\lambda)\geq0,\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.
However, I don't  have any idea about how to deal with $B$'s to make the determinant real. Can anyone help me?

What does $\overline B$ mean?

@kimchilover It is the conjugate of B.

Is $A\in M_n(\Bbb C)$? Or is $A\in GL_n(\Bbb C)$, like in the linked post?

The given condition implies that $\det(AR^2+I)$ is real nonnegative for all real square matrices $R$. If we take $R$ to be the idempotent matrix $e_i(e_i+te_j)^T$ where $i\ne j$ and $t\in\mathbb R$, then
$$
\det(AR^2+I)=\det(AR+I)
=(e_i+te_j)^TAe_i+1
=a_{ii}+ta_{ij}+1
$$
is real nonnegative for all $t\in\mathbb R$. Hence $A$ is a real diagonal matrix. However, as the condition that $\det(AR^2+I)\ge0$ is preserved under any real similarity transform, $A$ must remain diagonal under any real similarity transform. Therefore $A=kI$ for some real number $k$. Finally, by taking $R=\operatorname{diag}(r,0,\ldots,0)$, we have $0\le\det(AR^2+I)=kr^2+1$ for all real number $r$. Therefore $k\ge0$.

+1 You make everything so easy
